# como limitar la cantidad de cifras que introduce el usuariio?

Tags: java, validación, while, scanner

eneste caso quiero un codigo tenga que introducir un numero cualquiera que sea 8 cifras, en caso de que no escriba una cifra de 8 digitos el programa le arroja "escribe una cifra que tenga 8 digitos", este es mi codigo de momento:

```
        Scanner DNI = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero;

    System.out.println("Introduce solo los numeros de tu DNI");

    while (!DNI.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Causa solo los numeros");
        DNI.nextLine();
    }
    numero = DNI.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Perfecto");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes verificar si `numero > 99999999`. Si es así es mayor es porque tiene más de 8 dígitos.

Entonces pones parte del código que ya tienes dentro de un ciclo que haga esa verificación:

```
do {
    while (!DNI.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Causa solo los numeros");
        DNI.nextLine();
    }
    numero = DNI.nextInt();
} while (numero > 99999999);
```

O podrías obtener el número como un `String` y ver si su tamaño es 8 y convertirlo a número.

```
int numero;
String strNum = "";

do {
    while (!DNI.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Causa solo los numeros");
        DNI.nextLine();
    }
    String strNum = DNI.next();
} while (strNum.length() > 8);

numero = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
```